# Flutter multi-line text and image mixing problem

Tags: flutter

[image]I implemented the mixed arrangement of graphics and text through InlineSpan, but I encountered a little problem. When the text exceeds two lines, due to the setting of maxLines=2, the text takes up all the space and ends with..., resulting in the small icon at the end being invisible. Is there any way to solve this problem? Guys ,Thank you so much
**This is my implementation of mixed graphics and text**

```dart
 class TextHighlight extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextStyle? style; 
  final TextStyle? highlightStyle; 
  final String content; 
  final String? keyWord; 
  final int? maxLines; 
  final Widget? childTag;

  const TextHighlight({
    super.key,
    required this.content,
    this.keyWord,
    this.style,
    this.highlightStyle,
    this.maxLines,
    this.childTag,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<InlineSpan> spans = [];
    int start = 0;
    int end;
 
    spans.add(TextSpan(text: content.substring(start, content.length), style: style ?? GlobalStyleConfig.normalStyle));
    if (childTag != null) {
      spans.add(WidgetSpan(child: childTag!));
    }
    return RichText(
      maxLines: maxLines ?? 2,
      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
      text: TextSpan(children: spans),
    );
  }
}
```

I want the text in the middle to end with an ellipsis and then follow my tag icon

Comment: put your full code or remove the unnecessary parts (code for styling which is not connected to the question,...), so that one can copy-paste your code and easily test it, without having red errors on undefined variables.

Comment: Okay, I have pasted all the code, in which childTag can pass in any customized small icon